shell script does not detect file name correctly
I have the file named as: /home/cti/10min_test/CTI_poult_20240902005000.csv
and wrote this shell script below:
CURRENT_TIME=$(date -d "+1 hour +50 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M)
CURRENT_TIME_TRIMMED=${CURRENT_TIME:0:11}
FILE_NAME_PART=${CURRENT_TIME_TRIMMED}
echo "FILE_NAME_PART: ${FILE_NAME_PART}"
echo "SOAP PROJECT: Starting SFTP…"
lftp -d -u myuser,mypass sftp://myip:port <<EOF
mput /home/cti/10min_test/CTI_poult_${FILE_NAME_PART}*.csv
bye
EOF
echo "done"

And when this is executed, only shows this message:
FILE_NAME_PART: 20240902011
SOAP PROJECT: Starting SFTP…
*.csv: no files found_test/CTI_poult_20240902011
done

It seems "*.csv" is not properly processed by the script.
Anyone could tell me what the heck is wrong?

Are you sure this is the exact script?  The script has/home/cti/10min_test/, but the error message has found_test/.

Looks like you have a carriage return in the filename CTI_poult_20240902011\r*.csv -- make sure the script file iteself does not contain \r\n line endings. The dos2unix command is helpful.

The date part in CTI_poult_20240902005000.csv doesn't match your date code (date -d "+1 hour +50 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M,) Either you need to add %S, or remove the ending "Seconds stamp" of  00 .... better debugging can be achieved with set -x (set +x to disable) AND export PS4='${LINENO} >' (export PS4="+" is the default value) . It will show each Line of executed code with all env-vars, cmd-substitutions, etc, expanded so you know exactly what command the shell tried to Run. All dbl-quoted strings are "normalized" to single-quoted strings.  Good luck.

@glennjackman : I first also thought so, but wouldn't then the two echo be also messed up, the second one overwriting the first? But you are right, in that it would make sense to make a hex dump of the script and look for stray carriage returns.

You can also do a printf %s "$FILE_NAME_PART" | oc -cx and look for CRs or other control characters.

@user1934428, "wouldn't then the two echo be also messed up" -- no because echo adds a newline in addition to the (supposed) carriage return.

It turns out that my shell that I used was in windows system, resulting in having "\r' at the end of every single lines.... I just executed "bash -x soap_cti.sh" and found out this.. (having \r at the end of every line)

Here's how I solved this, I open up by vim(vi soap_cti.sh), and then input  :set ff=unix, and then :wq. This solved up everything! Thank you!


It seems "*.csv" is not properly processed by the script. Anyone could tell me what the heck is wrong?

Why "*.csv" is not properly processed by the script probably that the use of wildcards (*) inside the lftp command can not automatically expanded.
mput /home/cti/10min_test/CTI_poult_${FILE_NAME_PART}*.csv

What you can try to expand the wildcard in the shell before passing the files to lftp.
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_TIME=$(date -d "+1 hour +50 minutes" +%Y%m%d%H%M)
CURRENT_TIME_TRIMMED=${CURRENT_TIME:0:11}
FILE_NAME_PART=${CURRENT_TIME_TRIMMED}

echo "FILE_NAME_PART: ${FILE_NAME_PART}"
echo "SOAP PROJECT: Starting SFTP…"

# Expand the file path before passing it to lftp
FILES_TO_UPLOAD=$(ls /home/cti/10min_test/CTI_poult_${FILE_NAME_PART}*.csv 2>/dev/null)

if [ -z "$FILES_TO_UPLOAD" ]; then
  echo "No files found for pattern: /home/cti/10min_test/CTI_poult_${FILE_NAME_PART}*.csv"
else
  lftp -d -u myuser,mypass sftp://myip:port <<EOF
  mput ${FILES_TO_UPLOAD}
  bye
EOF
fi

echo "done"

